# How to Deploy secrets.json in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am using secrets.json to store username and password. How can I deploy to server?
or is there any different way like secrets.json?

Comment: You can always use environment variables in your target machine instead of using ~secrets.json

Comment: What is the best environment variables? @ Severius5

Comment: Deploying secrets.json will completely defeat the purpose of having it in the first place. Credentials and secrets should be stored inside secure places, like Azure Key Vault or similar services. As an alternative you may store them as environment variables inside the server (but they no longer will be secrets, of course).

Comment: So what's the point of a secrets.json "file" if you can't deploy it!?

Answer (score 1):

This file is for developers to store their own user password. you have to fill this file deployment information

Comment: I know about it but is there anyway to deploy?

Comment: I think you have to save these data somewhere else like appsetttings

Comment: That is copying your Information from secret.json to another json file that is deployable like appsettings.json . Why that doesn't work?

Comment: I am using appsettings.json now. But I wanted to exceptional something. @Sepehr Davarnia

Comment: Can someone please explain how to properly hide a ConnectionString when deploying to IIS? If the secrets file is for development only, shouldn't the EF design team have factored in a way to deploy a ConnectionString to IIS!? Seems a major oversight.